# Bootstrapping Dependencies (using StructureMap) in winforms

Tags: winforms, structuremap, bootstrapping

I am trying to keep the IoC registration off to the side just like it is done in CodeCampServer via the DependencyResolution project, so that only one project in my solution holds a reference to StructureMap.

I have implementations of interfaces in my Client/UI project which I want registered, meaning that this DependencyResolution Project needs to have a reference to my Client/UI project.

But how do I go about Bootstrapping the setup of the dependencies from within my Client/UI project without taking a reference to the DependencyResolution project to initiate the registration of the dependencies?

I have used the HttpModule method before from within an MVC application (similar to how CodeCampServer does it) but I'm trying to figure out how to do it in a WinForms app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cavet: I do not claim to have much experience with WinForms. I believe that the thrust of Jeremy's [Build Your Own CAB](http://codebetter.com/blogs/jeremy.miller/archive/2007/07/25/the-build-your-own-cab-series-table-of-contents.aspx) series of blog posts discusses the challenge of composing testable desktop applications.